# What does `when` mean inside ` ` in Kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I see in unit tests for Android created in Kotlin the code like this

```
`when`(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(sharedPreferences)
```

Could you explain me why `when` is inside `` ? If I remove `` around `when` I see an issue that `thenReturn` could not be resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`when` is a keyword in Kotlin, as it's used in the [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression). In Mockito, there is a static function that's also called [`when`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#when-T-). This can happen because `when` wasn't a keyword in Java, so it was available for identifier naming.

The backticks are [special syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin) that make these functions defined in Java still callable from Kotlin.

Ps. You might want to look into [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin), it makes a couple Mockito-related tasks simpler in Kotlin, for example it renames the `when` function to `whenever` so that it's easier and nicer to call.

Comment: `The backticks are special syntax that make these functions defined in Java still callable from Kotlin.` - Not just that though. They can also be called in Kotlin to escape normally illegal characters. For an instance, `**` doesn't compile, but `\`**\`` is. Though it's just generally easier just using non-reserved keywords and supported names, there are cases where the backticks can be used in function declaration (i.e. `fun \`**\`(something: Any)`)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to depend on another third party library as suggested in the accepted answer, you may want to take a look at [BDDMockito](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0/org/mockito/BDDMockito.html) (part of Mockito already). This basically just changes the style you write tests with Mockito and happens to provide Kotlin-friendly function names, which don't need to be escaped like `when`:

```
//Given
given(calcService.add(20.0,10.0)).willReturn(30.0);

//when
double result = calcService.add(20.0,10.0);

//then
Assert.assertEquals(result,30.0,0);
```